# tbl_summary() -- Multiple columns of Stats per each "by" group

Tags: r, gtsummary

It's well documented that we can tweak the summary stats under each grouping when using `by` in `tbl_summary`.

For example, say I'm doing:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gtsummary)
mtcars %>% select(vs, mpg) %>% tbl_summary(by = vs)
```

We know I can modify the summary stats for each VS group by using the "statistic argument": `mtcars %>% select(vs, mpg) %>% tbl_summary(by = vs, statistic = all_continuous() ~ "{mean} ({sd})")`

I love this ability. But if I want to report a lot of statistics -- say for instance I want min, max, median, mean, se, and IQR, it can get cluttered fast. What I'm wondering is if there's a way to split each group (from the `by` variable) into multiple summary stat columns.

That is, compared to this table (produced with the first chunk of code):

[image]

Is there a way to make gtsummary output it to have the summary stats split into multiple cells per grouping like this:
[image]

Thanks for any and all insight.

Comment: Haven't found an option in the docs for multiple columns but there is an option to have multiple rows of summary stats: https://www.danieldsjoberg.com/gtsummary/articles/tbl_summary.html#continuous2

Comment: There's a similar example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71652357 . You'll just need to split the calculation by your by variable, then merge the final two tables.

Comment: But I do recommend doing as @stefan suggested, using the `"continuous2"` summary type.